# How to increment index in Python loop

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, indices

I am wanting to loop through a string and capture 2 items each time while also incrementing through the index of the iterable. So I want to slice 2 items but increase the index by 1 every time through the loop. How can I do this?

my_string = 'teststring'

desired output =
te
es
st
ts
st
tr
ri
in
ng

I have tried the following to slice the two items, but can't figure out the best way to iterate thought the index

```
str1 = 'teststring'
i=0
while i<10: 
    i +=1
    str2=str1[0:2]
    print(str2)
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` just fine; you aren't *using* it in the slice, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can do this in a one-liner

```
s = 'teststring'

r = ' '.join([s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)])

print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution (`s` is your string):

```
for j in range(len(s) - 1):
    print(s[j:j + 2])
```

Another one:

```
for c1, c2 in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]):
    print(c1 + c2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = 'teststring'
result = []
for i in range(len(str1) - 1):
    result.append(str1[i:i + 2])

print(result)
```

output

```
['te', 'es', 'st', 'ts', 'st', 'tr', 'ri', 'in', 'ng']
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are trying to move both the start and end point of the slice with each iteration, you want to use the index+length of slice for the end point.

You should iterate after the slice is done. Here is the answer with minimal changes to your code:

```
str1 = 'teststring'
i=0
while i<=len(str1)-2: 
    str2=str1[i:i+2]
    i += 1
    print(str2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a for loop instead of a while loop, like this:

```py
def strangeSlice(string):
    out = ""
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        out += string[i:i+2]
        if i != len(string)-2:
            out += " "
    print(out)
    return out
def main():
    strangeSlice("teststring")
main() #you need to call the main function to run
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but thank you for the help.